# handling httpwebrequest.getresponse exception inside timer function

Tags: c#, timer

i'm using httpwebrequest.getresponse() inside function with timer. Timer calls this function every few seconds. However sometimes web server refuses to response due to quick request and response because of timer.

I need to make sure that function continues execution with timer and exception is handled properly.

or

what is the best way to handle http web request and web response for a function inside timer?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the exception the usual way, then?

```
try {
    // Send your request
} catch(WebException ex) {
    // It failed
}
```

Comment: ya i'm handling the exception but i need to make sure that exception is handled properly, in short providing solution inside exception so that function does not stop executing and things continue with timer smoothly

Comment: @user1502952: Just ignore it.

Comment: i have put httpwebresponse.getresponse() inside try/catch and inside catch running while loop checking if response==httpstatus.ok and response not equals null. if true break and this works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
while(response==null)
{

httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL + param);
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;

try
{
response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response != null)
{
 streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
 doc = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
 break;
}
}
catch (WebException exx)
{
Console.WriteLine("Trying to reconnect with Web Server");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
}
```